# Насколько необходимо знать Python в Data Science?

Tags: python

Сейчас активно изучаю python после с++ и назрел вопрос. Мне очень нравится писать код и продумывать логику и так же нравится математическое направление, поэтому думал пойти в DS и начал копать в этом направлении. Но пока по ощущениям и мои каким-то опытам, для DS (на самых ранних стадиях) знание ЯП сводится к какой-то базе. Понятно, что при дальнейшем развитии потребность в использовании языка возрастет.

Поэтому появился вопрос. Насколько необходимо знать python в ds и на сколько он там используется (или другой ЯП)? Например, в сравнении в какой-нибудь web-разработкой на нем же. Просто недавно занимался одним проектом, и все свелось к простому использованию библиотеки без какого-то написания личного кода.

Answer (score 5):

Python облегчает работу программисту, за счет использование множества библиотек, написанными за вас на C и Python (и кучей пряностей в виде динамической типизации, динамическим управлением памятью и т.д. и т.п.) если вам нравятся скобки, вручную объявлять типы переменных и потратить хз сколько времени на обучение программированию на C++ (в общем вы любитель хардкора), можете писать всё сами на C++ в DS (в большинстве случаев, это будут велосипеды), никто вас от этого не удержит.

Проще говоря, в случае анализа данных Python хорош набором качественных библиотек  конкретно для работы с данными (Pandas и всё в таком же духе, гугл в помощь), и для любителей математики могу порекомендовать ознакомиться с чисто функциональными ЯП (Haskell, Lisp).

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть из диаграммы, программирование или **Computer Science** - это лишь небольшая часть **Data Science**, при этом все нужные библиотеки и для статистики и для **Machine Learning** в основном давно уже написаны, только собирай из них код, как из кубиков, для чего достаточно и начальных знаний питона.

Поэтому продвинутое программирование в DS нужно только где-то на "переднем крае" - когда работаешь в компании, которая изобретает новые ML модели и их нужно программировать, причём нужно сделать, чтобы они работали достаточно быстро и эффективно. Или в компании, где очень много данных, стандартные модели с такими объёмами не справляются и нужно что-то придумывать своё.

В остальных случаях в DS именно программирование не нужно настолько, чтобы нужно было в него очень глубоко закапываться. Скорее там придётся больше изучать статистику и предметную область.

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ наиболее полный и актуальный)

Answer (score 0):

Питон обычный язык программирования для которого  нужен очень низкий вход. Порою достаточно знать просто синтаксис. Именно из-за свой не требовательности  к  знаниям  обширного API питон пихают везде и всюду. Конкретно для DS питон не несет каких-либо  дополнительных преимуществ также как и не недостатков. Все как со всеми языками программирования. Но если Вы ушли СРР, зачем(?) значит СРР Вас не устроил. Хотя этот язык имеет больше возможностей создания приложений для DS.